Thanks for 7 years of trust
Since yesterday I am not a mod. I am not going anywhere though.
I was about to resign but it happened automatically anyway because I didn't sign recent policy agreements. No politics here, I just wasn't motivated to read them.
I was not very active lately and felt I didn't put enough effort to resolving certain flags. Traffic is not what it used to be but the community still deserves the best service I can't always provide.
Thanks again and see you later

Thank you so much for these many years of service to our community!

Thanks for all the assists, Kuba.  Glad you will still be around.

A bit late, but thanks @Kuba :-)
